# how to reduce time for running query in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis, query-performance, postgresql-9.5

I have below query:

```
SELECT seq, node, edge, cost as cost, agg_cost, geom, sT_AsGeoJson(geom), replace(
    (REPLACE(sT_AsGeoJson(geom),
     ( select ST_AsGeoJson(geom1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647) a where seq1 in ( select  min(seq1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647 ))),
   (SELECT (St_asgeoJson(ST_LineSubstring((select (geom1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647) a where seq1 in (select  min(seq1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647 ))),(select ST_LineLocatePoint((select st_astext(geom1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647) a where seq1 in (select  min(seq1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647 ))), (ST_MakePoint(20.9850904,52.2318352)))),1)))
    ))),
     ( select ST_AsGeoJson(geom1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647) a where seq1 in ( select  max(seq1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647 ))),
    (SELECT st_asgeojson((ST_LineSubstring((select (geom1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647) a where seq1 in (select  max(seq1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647 ))),0,(select ST_LineLocatePoint
                ((select st_astext(geom1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647) a where seq1 in (select  max(seq1) from sample(20.983455,52.231909,20.973400,52.169647 ))), (ST_MakePoint(20.9741841,52.1691584)))))))
     ))
      FROM pgr_dijkstra 
    ('SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom, true) as cost FROM roads',
      (SELECT source FROM roads ORDER BY ST_Distance( ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(20.983455, 52.231909), 4326), true ) ASC LIMIT 1),
      (SELECT target FROM roads ORDER BY ST_Distance( ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(20.973400, 52.169647), 4326), true ) ASC LIMIT 1)) as pt
     JOIN roads rd ON pt.edge = rd.id;
```

While running query it's taking 30 seconds.

Is there any way to reduce time for executing.

Comment: To make the question answerable, please format the query better and add the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) `.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce time You need to care about :

1. The complexity of your query, for example if your sub-query is going to turn 'N' times so the whole query is going to take O(N POW(M)) where M is Total of records of the Query,
2. After simplifying the complexity, Indexes are used to speed up the performance of queries.
3. Use Primary key to identify records in tables easily
4. Try to avoid 'Limit' keyword n sub-Query
5. Try to avoid Group functions in sub-Query

e.g : in your 'WHERE' clause you have this "pt.edge = rd.id"
You can create an index of the combination of the two columns edge and id  in the table Referenced